# RNN model: Infer on sentences longer than max sequence length used during training

Tags: tensorflow

I am training a RNN model (using `rnn.dynamic_rnn` method) and my data matrix is of the shape `num_examples x max_sequence_length x num_features`. During training, I do not want to increase `max_sequence_length` to more than 50 or 100, since it increases the training time and memory. All the sentences in my training set was less than 50. However, during testing, I want the model to be able to infer on up to 500 tokens. Is it possible? How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

@sonal - Yes it is possible . Because , in testing most of the time , we are interested in passing a single example , rather than a bunch of data . 
So , what you need is , you need to pass the array of single example lets say

```
test_index = [10 , 23 , 42 ,12 ,24, 50]
```

to a dynamic_rnn . The prediction has to happen based on the final hidden state . Inside dynamic_rnn , I think you can pass sentences beyond max_length in training . If it is not , you can write a custom decoder function , to calculate the GRU or LSTM states , with the weights you obtained while training . The idea is you can continue generate the output until you reach a maximum length for a testing case or until the model generated a 'EOS' special token . I prefer , you make use of a decoder , after you get the final hidden state from the encoder , this will give better results also .

```
# function to the while-loop, for early stopping
    def decoder_cond(time, state, output_ta_t):
        return tf.less(time, max_sequence_length)

    # the body_builder is just a wrapper to parse feedback
    def decoder_body_builder(feedback=False):
        # the decoder body, this is where the RNN magic happens!
        def decoder_body(time, old_state, output_ta_t):
            # when validating we need previous prediction, handle in feedback
            if feedback:
                def from_previous():
                    prev_1 = tf.matmul(old_state, W_out) + b_out
                    a_max = tf.argmax(prev_1, 1)
                    #### Try to find the token index and stop the condition until you get a EOS token index . 
                    return tf.gather(embeddings, a_max )
                x_t = tf.cond(tf.equal(time, 0), from_previous, lambda: input_ta.read(0))
            else:
                # else we just read the next timestep
                x_t = input_ta.read(time)

            # calculate the GRU
            z = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x_t, W_z_x) + tf.matmul(old_state, W_z_h) + b_z) # update gate
            r = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x_t, W_r_x) + tf.matmul(old_state, W_r_h) + b_r) # reset gate
            c = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(x_t, W_c_x) + tf.matmul(r*old_state, W_c_h) + b_c) # proposed new state
            new_state = (1-z)*c + z*old_state # new state

            # writing output
            output_ta_t = output_ta_t.write(time, new_state)

            # return in "input-to-next-step" style
            return (time + 1, new_state, output_ta_t)
        return decoder_body
    # set up variables to loop with
    output_ta = tensor_array_ops.TensorArray(tf.float32, size=1, dynamic_size=True, infer_shape=False)
    time = tf.constant(0)
    loop_vars = [time, initial_state, output_ta]

    # run the while-loop for training
    _, state, output_ta = tf.while_loop(decoder_cond,
                                        decoder_body_builder(feedback = True),
                                        loop_vars,
                                        swap_memory=swap)
```

This is just a snippet code , try to modify it accordingly . More details can found in https://github.com/alrojo/tensorflow-tutorial