# Use RNN for classifying text with variable length

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

In the lastest tensorflow `tf.contrib.layers.embed_sequence()` is used for classifying text with fixed-length.
I want to know if *RNN* can classify text with variable length?
And is there any *API* in tensorflow about this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not written in the current API documentation.  If you need to vary the length pick a large length and pad your sentences.

```
embed_sequence(ids,
              vocab_size=None,
              embed_dim=None,
              unique=False,
              initializer=None,
              regularizer=None,
              trainable=True,
              scope=None,
              reuse=None)
```

For comments and notes in the source code go [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/d86d570faaa63cf7815a55379d91919ffde2699d#diff-b3a2a62db345de7e16a8873c920d0d50R91).

You might find these links useful:
[Variable Sequence Lengths in TensorFlow](https://danijar.com/variable-sequence-lengths-in-tensorflow/), [Tensorflow RNN with varying length sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34670112/tensorflow-rnn-with-varying-length-sentences)

Comment: Maybe it's not very well expressed.I have used it before and it worked very well.As we know,text is always with different length.For examples,if ids is[[0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]],can RNN train?I wonder if we need new function about that.Thank you for your help!